# 2 svn -> 1 git. How to map two svn repositories into one git with two branches with common origin?

Tags: git, branch, git-svn

The project I work on was divided on 2 projects one year ago. For this svn repository was copied to another location and work was continued into 2 different svn repositories.

Now I have to merge these 2 projects into one. For these I would like to have a local git repository with 2 branches, each of those mapped to one of svn repositories.
Is it possible?

I know that I can create 2 remotes branches in git, but **how to explain git that these branches have a common origin?**

Comment: If you want to keep a clean history, you need to find the common ancestor commit of the 2 SVN projects and create the GIT repo from there. Then you can create two branches with the rest of the commits and merge the 2 branches manually

Comment: @Joucks, what do you mean create GIT repo from commit? How to create two branches with the rest of the commits?

Comment: I mean checkout the revision of the code just before the two projects diverged and from there use a "svn to git" tool to convert the project.

Comment: @Joucks, it feels like you missed "work was continued into 2 different svn repositories". If not, could you make full instructions list for me ,please?