# Copy chain of commits between repositories

Tags: git, svn, version-control, patch, git-commit

How can I copy a chain of commits from one git (or svn) repository to another?

If I would have only one commit I would do:

```
 cd Git1
 git diff commitHash^ commitHash > patch.txt
 cd Git2
 git branch CommitsFromGit1
 git checkout CommitsFromGit1
 patch -i ....Git1/patch.txt
 git ci -am "CommitFromGit1Name"
```

But I have too many commits to proceed manually one by one. Is there a way to create somekind of multi-patch, with a set of commits-changes?

Comment: Are Git1 and Git2 two clones of the same repository ?

Comment: @Joucks, They are copies of two svn repositories with common origin. The original problem I try to solve is described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20426269/2-svn-1-git-how-to-map-two-svn-repositories-into-one-git-with-two-branches-w

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's call your gits A and B and say you're working on the master branch. While in git A, add B as a remote and fetch its contents into A:

```
git remote add B /path/to/B
git fetch B
```

(You don't have to add it as a remote; you can just do `git fetch /path/to/B master:B/master` if you like. This copies all branches in B which might be unnecessary in your case. Feel free to specify an explicit refspec to limit the fetch.)

Now you can use `git-cherrypick` to copy individual commits from B to A, or use `git rebase --onto` to copy multiple commits. The latter command has this general form:

```
git rebase --onto destination boundary starting_point
```

Git walks backwards from `starting_point` until it reaches `boundary` and copies the resulting commits (excluding `boundary`) onto the tip of `destination`. Thus, this copies the three most recent commits from B's master branch to A's master branch:

```
git rebase --onto master B/master~3 B/master
```

Comment: I think of `rebase --onto` in this way: `git rebase --onto <newbase> <oldbase> <head>`. Basically, you're calling out the base you want it on, then the base it's currently on, and then the tip of the thing you're moving. I.e. "Change the base to that base, from this base, for this thing."